# Assertion Failed nbytes==sizeof (dummy) zeromq/src/signaler.cpp:402 Python.exe stopped working - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was successfully able to install Jupyter Notebook, with Anaconda. Everything was working fine, until suddenly one fine day I started to receive this message. Its happening when my Kernel is running for about continuous 1-1.5 hrs continuously.
[image]

I had gone through all possible solutions over Github, and did the following stuffs:

1. Uninstalled networkx
2. Turned off Firewall
3. Checked whether there is any anti-virus in my system, but there is none.

Since doing these did not fix the issue and ultimately I uninstalled zmq:

`pip uninstall zmq` and now I get this message:

[image]

Although I'm getting this message, but it seems that its not crashing automatically, I have to check for a longer time though. But I think that I'm doing something wrong, or something is there I'm not able to understand.

My OS is Windows 10, with only Windows Defender (Real-Time Protection) turned on, but previously also I had my Firewall and Defender both on, but never had this issue, suddenly I'm having all this problem. I didn't install anything, nothing.

I have found that if you change the port no. in `signaler.cpp` file, it may solve the issue, but at least if someone can help me locate the file atleast, I'm not able to find it under library folder in Anaconda packages.

P.S. If anyone can also tell me the significance of `zmq` library and whether it is important to keep it. Also I'm getting `ssl error` everytime I try to `pip-install` a module. So I have to write extra trusted link to do the installation.

Comment: zmq is used by Jupyter to manage the TCP connections (https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/messaging.html) and an assertion failure looks a lot as a bug in this zmq to me

Comment: so you think I should install it? but then when I install it, I get assertion failed error, and this started happening all of a sudden.